# Google AppEngine automatic scaling (back down)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-php

I have a php AppEngine app.  No scaling config, I'm just using the defaults.

Yesterday it's scaled up to two instances when I was doing some heavy testing.  It's only handled one or two requests since then, but is still running 2 instances.  How long does it take to scale back down?  That was more than 24 hours ago.  Thanks!

Comment: btw, you can always stop it manually

Comment: They may keep it running but they won't charge you for it. Take a look on the Instances chart.

Answer (score 0):

They usually spin down after 15 minutes. However it will depend heavily on your application profile, and is not guaranteed.

You can configure the maximum idle instances and then they guarantee not to bill you above that threshold.